# Type 'MapViewController' has no member 'mapTypeChanged' Swift Big Nerd Ranch Guide

Tags: ios, swift

[Type 'MapViewController' has no member 'mapTypeChanged'][2]
in line:

```
action: #selector(MapViewController.mapTypeChanged(_:)),
```

There is a method `mapTypeChanged` at the bottom of the code, so I'm unsure why the error says there is no member `mapTypeChanged` ? I'm guessing mapTypeChanged needs to be declared as a variable (global?)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func loadView() {

        mapView = MKMapView()
        view = mapView

        let segmentedControl
            = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor
            = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self,
                                   action: #selector(MapViewController.mapTypeChanged(_:)),
                                   for: .valueChanged)
segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

        let topConstraint
            = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        let leadingConstraint =
            segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingConstraint =
            segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)

        topConstraint.isActive = true
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        trailingConstraint.isActive = true

        func mapTypeChanged(_segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch _segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                mapView.mapType = .standard
            case 1:
                mapView.mapType = .hybrid
            case 2:
                mapView.mapType = .satellite
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("MapViewController Loaded its view.")

    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question by copying and pasting actual code as text into your question. And please be sure it's formatted properly.

Comment: I edited my post - however, some of the code was snipped out and I couldn't format it properly. Any help would be awesome, thanks! @rmaddy

Comment: Edit your post, select all of the code, type Ctrl-K to indent it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Edited it again. @rmaddy

Comment: 1. Your error is about `segControl`. 2. The code you posted makes no mention of `segControl`. 3. Update your question with the actual code causing the issue. 4. Clearly indicate which lines exactly are causing the errors.

Comment: Edited again. Thanks! @rmaddy

Comment: You still haven't fixed issues 1, 2, and 4. Your question still talks about an error about `segControl` but there is still no mention of `segControl` in your posted code. There is now a variable named `_segControl` but that's not the same thing. So one last time. Please update your question with real exact error messages, real code, and clearly point out which lines show which error messages. You are making it extremely difficult and frustrating to help you.

Comment: My apologies. There is no longer an error regarding 'segControl' after I noticed a typo. The only error now is a "Type 'MapViewController' has no member 'mapTypeChanged'. The line that is causing the error is 'action: #selector(MapViewController.mapTypeChanged(_:)),'. I've updated the question as well. Please excuse my ignorance, I'm just getting started with iOS programming, Swift, and how to use StackOverflow. @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

```
#selector(MapViewController.mapTypeChanged(_:))
```

means "call `mapTypeChanged` method".

So You need to implement `mapTypeChanged`.

```
func mapTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Comment: Beside putting a space between the `_` and `sender` in the method declaration, the `mapTypeChanged` method also needs to be moved out from the `loadView` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This worked. I really appreciate you sticking with me on this one with all my miscues.

Comment: You’re welcome. If my answer resolved your issue please accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 9.3.1 the function mapTypeChanged must be **outside** `override func loadView()` and preceded by @objc:

```
@objc func mapTypeChanged(_ segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            ...
        }
    }
```

The @objc attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime.